# php regex for min and max number length

Tags: php, regex

```
if(strlen(trim($steamid)) != 0)
            {
                $regex = "/^STEAM_0:(0|1):[0-9]{1}[0-9]{0,8}$/";
                if(!ereg($regex, $ssteamid)){
                    echo "STEAM ID invalida";
                }
            }
```

My problem is that this isn't working as it should.

STEAM ID's have maximum of 18 characters and minimum of 17.

they always start with: STEAM_0:

Two true examples would be: STEAM_0:0:11111111 ; STEAM_0:1:1111111

And another thing is that after STEAM_0: always come an 0 or an 1 like demonstrated in the examples.

Comment: There's no max or minimum to steam ids.

Answer (score 3):

This:

```
$regex = "/^STEAM_0:(0|1):[0-9]{1}[0-9]{0,8}$/";
```

could be writter shorter as:

```
$regex = "/^STEAM_0:[01]:[0-9]{1,9}$/";
```

Since your ID is 17 or 18 chars long, adjust the regex to it:

```
$regex = "/^STEAM_0:[01]:[0-9]{7,8}$/";
```

Finally, note that `ereg` is deprecated as of PHP 5.3. This snippet shows your php/regex with [`preg_match`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php):

```
<?php

$steamid = "STEAM_0:0:11111111";

if(strlen(trim($steamid)) != 0)
{
    $regex = "/^STEAM_0:[01]:[0-9]{7,8}$/";
    if(!preg_match($regex, $steamid))
    {
        echo "STEAM ID invalida.\n";
    } else {
        echo "STEAM ID valida.\n";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Replacing `(0|1)` with `[01]` would prevent capturing, and therefore improve performance.

Comment: it doesnt work, the STEAM ID is just like this: STEAM_0:1:2796878

Comment: if you can make this work for the steamid that I posted above it works for everyother attending the conditions in my original post

Answer (score 0):

If the minimum length is 17 and the max length is 18, then you guys are looking at this at the wrong way.
This should do the job for you:

```
$regex = "/^STEAM_0:(0|1):[0-9]{7}[0-9]?$/";
```

And also, when in doubt, test your regexp with some of the online regexp tools like http://www.regexplanet.com/simple/index.html

Comment: I just found out that something in the code was wrong, if you notice in my original post there ssteamid insted of steamid, I corrected it but still with your regex it isnt working, am I using thw wrong function? instead of ereg should I be using something else?

Comment: Yeah, `eregi` is deprecated, you can achieve the same thing with `preg_match`. See http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php for usage.

Comment: You can write `[0-9]{7}[0-9]?` as `[0-9]{7,8}`.

Comment: @Gumbo, yup thanks, I honestly don't know why I went for this approach.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$regex = "/^STEAM_0:(0|1):[0-9]{8,9}$/";
```

It matches:

- `STEAM_0:` at the beginning, followed
  by
- a `0` or a `1`, followed by a `:`,
  followed by
- Either 8 or 9 digits, making the
  total number of characters 17 or 18

Answer (score 0):

You should be avoiding use of `ereg()` and its related functions; they've deprecated for quite a long time in PHP. Use the`preg_xx()` functions instead (`preg_match()` in this case).

One of the differences between preg_match() and ereg() is that ereg() does not expect you to include the slash characters to start and end the regex, whereas preg_match() does. This is probably the main reason your code isn't working: since you've included the slashes, your use of ereg() won't work, but is you switch to preg_match(), the same expression should work fine.

So a simple change to preg_match() should sort you problem. But while I'm here, I may also suggest that you can shorten your regex string quite considerably. Try something like this:

```
$regex = "/^STEAM_0:[01]:[0-9]{8,9}$/";
if(!preg_match($regex, $ssteamid)) {
    echo "STEAM ID invalid";
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks you all , I think all your regex work, the thing is I was using ereg, thanks for your explanations :) it works now

Comment: If the advice has helped you, please "accept" one of the answers by clicking the tick icon next to it. :-)